# How to do recurring subscriptions with credit card and Drupal 7

Tags: commerce

I need to implement recurring payments properly for my site. The payment model I have in mind is that as in use by linode: you sign up, pay for a linode and it will be billed forever recurring to your credit card. If you choose to make that linode larger, or order another one, you'll still be billed only once at the first day of the month, except now with the new amount.

Is there a decent module to do this under Drupal 7? I'm looking at drupal commerce and the commerce_moneybookers module (since i already have a moneybookers merchant account) but moneybookers only provides recurring payments if you sign up for an account with them. I'm not prepared to make my customers do that.

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been doing a bunch of research, and it seems there are two main contenders for my scenario: http://www.fastspring.com and http://www.moneyscripts.net/drupal-membership-suite

I like the second one because it is pure drupal. But I like fastspring because it's very easy to use and pricing seems to be moderate. They also offer a great range of payment methods and they are PCI-DSS certified.

I'll do some more research and let you know my final choice

Comment: Chose fastspring in the end for their great support and nice features. Not yet in production, but very happy so far!

Comment: Yesterday I found out from http://trends.builtwith.com/payment/ that a lot of people use ccbill.com. Their service looks good, but the fastspring service has been exceptional so far, so sticking with them (and recommending them!)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but I have heard some interesting thoughts about this in [Lullabot Podcast #99](http://www.lullabot.com/podcasts/lullabot-podcast-99-drupalizeme-1-year-retrospective). The main takeaway was that they're very happy with the services from [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't authorized.net very US-specific? Can I use it as a European citizen?

Comment: Good question, but I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I emailed them and they said they couldn't have me as a customer. You need to have a US taxpayer number. They did refer me to their partner/parent/whatever: www.cybersource.co.uk. Seems like they offer the same services, just more international.

Comment: Lullabot does not seem to be using Commerce,  btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can do recurring billing with Ubercart and uc_recurring.

You can use authorize.net ARB or CIM, or Paypal WPP

Comment: I don't even see why this is reccommended. The solution is absolutely terrible for recurring subscriptions unless you are using Paypal WPP or Authorize.net

Comment: @dewayne you're right, it was a bad idea. We eventually switched to WordPress because drupal is a pos. Where is your positive contribution anyway? I didn't see an answer from you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [MoneySuite](https://www.drupal.org/project/moneysuite) is the best option if looking for a Drupal module/suite, and not an external service.  It's the successor to [MoneyScripts](https://www.moneyscripts.net/).

From the project page:

> This project is differentiated from the existing commerce modules in
>   that it requires no special adaptation for the sale of memberships and
>   handles one time or recurring payments through a variety of payment
>   gateways.